# Fit for a parameter when the function is obtained by numerical integration in Python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, numerical-integration

I have the code below in python. What it does is to integrate numerically the function `func` between 2 values and save the last value in `counts_list`. One of the parameters of `func` is `omega_Rabi`. What I need to do is, after I obtain `counts_list` I would like to perform a fit of `counts_list` vs `delta_list` (knowing that `counts_list` was obtained from `func`) and get `omega_Rabi`. Basically I assume I know `counts_list` and I want to find `omega_Rabi` that generate it (which now I assume I don't know). How can I do this? I usually use `curve_fit` but the stuff I tried so far didn't work. Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

pi = np.pi

omega = 2*pi*50000
omega_Rabi = 2*pi*170*6 

def func(t, y, omega, delta, omega_Rabi): 
    c_up, c_down = y
    dydt = [-1j*(omega_Rabi*np.sin(omega*t))*c_down,-1j*(omega_Rabi*np.sin(omega*t))*c_up-1j*delta*c_down]
    return dydt

t_init = 0
t_fin = 0.00005
t_eval =np.arange(t_init,t_fin,t_fin/10000)

delta_list = 2*pi*np.arange(-10000,10001,4000) 
delta_list = delta_list[np.where(delta_list != 0)] 

counts_list = np.zeros(len(delta_list))

y0 = [0+0j,1+0j]
for i in range(len(delta_list)):
    delta = delta_list[i]
    sol = solve_ivp(func, [t_init,t_fin], y0,rtol=1e-9, atol=1e-11, t_eval=t_eval, args=(omega,delta,omega_Rabi))
    y_up = abs(sol["y"][0])**2 

    counts_list[i] = y_up[-1]
```

Comment: "Basically I assume I know counts_list and I want to find omega_Rabi that generate it" Can you give an example of a counts_list you want to match?

Comment: @NickODell So in my problem I generate a counts_list for a given omega_Rabi, than using that obtained counts_list I want to fit it and get back the omega_Rabi used to produce it. I basically want to find a way to fit for omega_Rabi, knowing what omega_Rabi I expect to get from the fit. Of course in the real scenario I won't know omega_Rabi, but I am using the code above to test my fitting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will do the trick:

```
def model(x, w):
    y = []
    for z in x:
        sol = integrate.solve_ivp(func, [t_init, t_fin], y0, rtol=1e-9, atol=1e-11, t_eval=t_eval, args=(omega, z, w))
        y.append(np.abs(sol["y"][0][-1])**2)
    return np.array(y)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, delta_list, counts_list)
# (array([6408.84901332]), array([[1.80007176e-24]]))
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this works. If i run it without any noise, it gives me the right value. But as soon as I add some gaussian noise, the value is completely off and the uncertainty (from pcov) is virtually zero. I am not sure what is happening. What I did was, instead of returning the output of the numerical integration, I generate events assuming a binomial distribution given by the output of the numerical integration.

Comment: I basically have this in the output function now:         prob = np.abs(sol["y"][0][-1])**2
        counts.append(np.sum(np.random.binomial(1,np.ones(int(N))*prob))/N)
    return np.array(counts). This gives the exactly same plot you have above but with some noise on top.